# Problems with MySQL MATCH AGAINST

Tags: mysql

I'm using MATCH AGAINST to search against multiple fields in the database, but am having trouble with the results.

The query is:

```
MATCH(productname, stockcode, productdescription, additional_1, additional_2, additional_3, additional_4, additional_5, additional_6, additional_7, additional_8) AGAINST ('red* tile*' IN BOOLEAN mode)
```

From the query, I would like both "red%" or "tile%" results, but this is returning records where the word 'requiRED' is included, which I don't want.

Can this be done?

Comment: Do the records returned contain `tile*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, you have `ft_min_word_len` set to default value of `4`.

`red` does not get indexed or matched in this setup and just ignored in the queries.

Change `ft_min_word_len` to a lesser value if you want to match `red` (requires rebuilding the index if you have one).

See [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbbe5/2).

**Update:**

If you want both words matched, use this:

```
AGAINST ('+red* +tile*' IN BOOLEAN mode)
```

Comment: @JezB: if you have a fulltext index on the fields, you need to rebuild it.

Comment: That's fixed it - thank you! Now just gotta sort the data out :)

Comment: BTW - hadn't heard of sqlfiddle.com - it's brilliant... thanks!